# Creating a new Model Entry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Am I doing this correctly?

```
        using (UserContext context = new UserContext())
        {
            User user = context.Users.Create();

            user.Username = username;
            user.Email = email;
            user.IsDisabled = false;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

When I pass through this bit of code, my database never gets updated with a new entry. No errors are being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create in EF doesn't add the entity to the DBSet. You could Attach it, but it is more convenient to use the Add() method:

```
using (UserContext context = new UserContext())
        {
             context.Users.Add( new User {

          Username = username,
          Email = email,
          IsDisabled = false
                });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

before `context.SaveChanges()` Add this

```
context.Entry(User ).State = EntityState.Modified;
```